# How can I implement LoginComponent using Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am implementing a system using Angular 6, I am having trouble in routing. I made the entire 'Admin' part and this is the structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-background-color="white" data-active-color="danger">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        <div class="content">

            <router-outlet></router-outlet>

        </div>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</div>
<app-fixedplugin></app-fixedplugin>
```

My problem is, how can I implement the LoginComponent. Do I need to include the LoginComponent to the router-outlet?

Comment: Yeah.. implement a login route and only allow user to enter when authenticated. You may want to look into route gaurds.

Comment: For example, I have a DashboardComponent and DetailsComponent inside the router-outlet, do I need to reload the SidebarComponent as well as the FooterComponent everytime I am re-routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create separate component for login

```
ng g component login
```

This will create `LoginCompoent`

After that you need to add route path for LoginCompoent in `app.module.ts`

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './home/login.component';

@ngModule({
  imports: [
            BrowserModule, 
            RouterModule.forRoot([
              {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
              { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
           ])
          ]
})
```

Then restart your `ng` server.

Now you can use LoginComponent using the path `localhost:4200/login` or `localhost:4200/#/login`

Comment: Thank you. My problem is do I need to include FooterComponent and SidebarComponent everytime I am entering in the route that is dedicated for the Admin? Example, i am re-routing to DashboardComponent, do I need to include app-sidebar and app-footer everytime?

Comment: No need. Just include app-sidebar and app-footer in app.component.html. Any element in app.compoent.html is visible to entire application. You can disply by condition using *ngIf when you want to display the element. Ex: `<app-footer *ngIf="isAdmin"></app-footer>`. To know more about how to use *ngIf visit `https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf`

Comment: I am thinking of that. But I am not sure about it, I just want to make it clear. Thank you for helping!